# Visual Studio 2015 Web Express

Tags: visual-studio, sharepoint, licensing, visual-studio-2015

Are you allowed to develop commercial SharePoint Products using "VS 2015 Express for Web"? We just realized that with 2015 you need to have a MSDN subscription. Since we're primarily developing SharePoint solutions we're wondering if we could use the Express edition aswell.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Microsoft VS website](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-express-vs.aspx)

> **Commercial use of Express products**
>
> Visual Studio Express products are available at no charge and may be used for commercial, production usage subject to the license terms provided with each product. For example, you can use Express for Windows to create apps that you can then submit for sale in the Windows Store.

I would look deeper into the license of the VS Express 2015 for Web to be totally sure, but this looks like a "yes."

Comment: Hey Marcus, found those information too, but couldn't find what's behind: "subject to the license terms". The examples stated for VS Web Express don't contain SharePoint, but they do contain ASP.NET so I was curious.